# .NET Core - HTTPClient - dh key too small on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, openssl, dotnet-httpclient

I'd like to ask if there's a way to bypass Ubuntu's security checks so that I could be able to fetch a website with a small key in my .NET Core Client app? I am getting `error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small` exception.

The issue is that in Ubuntu 20.04 openSSL has security level set to `2` and (currently, hopefully someone will come up with an answer for [my question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level)) I have no idea how to set it to a lower value.

The same error occurs using `curl` unless `--ciphers 'DEFAULT:!DH'` parameter is provided, so I assume the root cause of the problem is within the operating sysem itself.

I do not control the website's server, so changing its security settings is a no go.

What I've tried so far from C# side:

```cs
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<IInterface, IImplementation>()
                             .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(messageHandlerBuilder =>
                             {
                                 messageHandlerBuilder.PrimaryHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                                 {
                                     ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, c, ch, e) => true
                                 };
                             });
```

and

```cs
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

var websiteContent = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
```

Security is not much of an issue in this case so I'm ok with using any dirty hack here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to the [answer received on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233456) I managed to fix the issue by:

- copying `openssl.cnf` file
- Adding `openssl_conf = default_conf` at the top of the copied file
- Adding at the end:

```
    [ default_conf ]

    ssl_conf = ssl_sect

    [ssl_sect]

    system_default = ssl_default_sect

    [ssl_default_sect]
    MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
    CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

- Running the project with `OPENSSL_CONF` environmental variable set to path to the altered config file

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it for me. After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS my wget refused to connect to a server I had previously copied files from. With this modification of openssl.cnf it works again.

Comment: New install of Ubuntu Server 20.04.  PHP Curl was throwing this error.  Added the above to openssl.cnf and it worked.  Thanks!